Intermittent OAuth Errors with NextAuth and Azure AD: Callback and Signin Timeout Issues
I'm using NextAuth (4.24.7) with Azure AD as my authentication provider in a Next.js 14 application. The setup works correctly sometimes, but more often than not, users are redirected back to the login page with the callback URL and an error in the query string.
My Authentication Flow:

Windows Login Only: I use Azure AD exclusively to authenticate users via their Windows login.
Custom Backend Call: After the user is authenticated by Azure AD, I make a call to my own backend to store the user's information. This is used to identify the user and fetch additional data.

My Provider Configuration:
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";
import axiosInstance from "@/core-libraries/http/axiosWithProxy";

const handleBackEnd = async (token: any) => {
  try {
    const authToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_SECRET;
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.post(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_API}/login`,
      {
        email: token.email,
        name: token.name,
        authToken,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      },
    );

    if (!data.isSucceeded) {
      throw new Error("Error logging in");
    }

    return {
      userToken: data.data.token,
      userRole: data.data.userRoles[0].role.title,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in handleBackEnd:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "login", // Force re-authentication
          scope: "openid profile user.Read email",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      },
    },
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  logger: {
    error(code, ...message) {
      console.error("ERROR - Next", code, message);
    },
    warn(code, ...message) {
      console.warn("WARN - Next", code, message);
    },
    debug(code, ...message) {
      console.debug("DEBUG Next", code, message);
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/logout",
    error: "/auth-error",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        try {
          const data = await handleBackEnd(token);
          token.user = {
            token: data.userToken,
            role: data.userRole,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("ERROR trying to login:", error);
        }
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.email = token.email as string;
      session.name = token.name as string;
      session.token = token.user?.token;
      return session;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      if (url.includes("error=OAuthCallback")) {
        return `${baseUrl}/auth-error`;
      }
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


The Problem:
Intermittently, instead of being logged in successfully, users are redirected back to the login page with a callback URL that includes an error parameter. The URLs returned sometimes look like this:

https://example.com/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&error=OAuthSignin
https://example.com/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&error=OAuthCallback
https://example.com/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

Error Logs:
Additionally, I'm seeing the following errors in the logs:
ERROR - Next OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR [
   {
     error: i: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms
     at ...
     ...
   },
   providerId: 'azure-ad'
]

OAuth Signin Error:
ERROR - Next SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR [
   {
     error: i: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms
     at ...
     ...
   },
   providerId: 'azure-ad'
]

These logs suggest that the outgoing request to Azure AD is timing out, which might be causing the intermittent failures during both the OAuth signin and callback stages.
Observations:

The issue is inconsistent. Sometimes the login process works perfectly, and other times it fails with the aforementioned errors.
I've tried to ensure that the configuration is correct, especially the cookies and session handling.

Question:
What could be causing these intermittent timeouts during the OAuth flow with Azure AD, and how can I ensure that the callback URL correctly redirects the user after authentication? Are there any specific configurations or best practices in handling Azure AD with NextAuth that I might be overlooking?
